# Why can't select data contain value of Tab?

Tags: sql, vb.net, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a Table A(C text): 
  value of Columns C contain value 'Tab' character:

```
 Re CX: 3m 1n, 
        CX 1  3t 
    [w R rr a (N)]
    Eor.
    ᄽlieter6ᄿ: L
    t: Tt
```

Query get data:

```
SELECT   *
FROM A

where C     = 'Re CX: 3m 1n, 
    CX 1  3t 
[w R rr a (N)]
Eor.
ᄽlieter6ᄿ: L
t: Tt'
```

Result : can't get data

Why can't select data contain value of Tab?

Note: if i delete value of Tab in database and Query, it can get data.

Comment: Is this MySQL or PostgreSQL?  They're not the same thing.  How are you executing this query?  A query analyzer, or a programming language?

Comment: It is PostgreSQL. exe by PgAdmin, vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an [escape string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

```
SELECT   *
FROM A
where C = E'Re CX: 3m 1n, \n\tCX 1  3t \n[w R rr a (N)]\nEor.\n?lieter6?: L\nt: Tt'
```

Note that I have no idea where the tab actually is in your string.  I'm totally guessing.

Comment: i try enscape, but it is not ok